# Colors based on category types

Tags: color-theory

I'm curious as to what type of colors would be good to use based on these categories

1. High school
2. College
3. Military
4. Corporate
5. Business
6. Charities

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! As it stands this question will result in purely opinion-based answers. Unfortunately, these types of questions aren't very helpful to anyone but perhaps, you. If you can reword the question so that answers can be less subjective it may be better.

Comment: Genres of *what*? Also, what scott said.

Comment: @DA01 Categories is that better? lol Man I just want to bounce some ideas off some people for color ideas. It's not a hard question to answer. Example, if you had to pick a color that represents those categories what would you choose? 

I'm sorry is this not a place where I can talk to other designers and get there input? If not I appologize and I'll remove my question.

Comment: At that generic level, it really doesn't matter. It's such a wide range of concepts that as long as the colors work together, it's less important what each color is vs. that they are just distinct. It's not a bad question--but not a good question for this format, as it really is just a matter of opinion in this case.

Comment: @DA01 I realize what you are saying, but in my case it's important what colors represent the categories. I would simple like to hear other designers opinions. What colors would you choose DA01 to represent those categories?

Comment: dagaard47, I understand you want *opinions* but Stack Exchange sites aren't designed for supplying purely opinions. Questions need to have relatively definitive answers. There's no possible way anyone could definitively answer this question. I imagine every color in the spectrum is used for a "high school color" at some point. There's no way anyone could site references that emphatically state color X, Y and Z are always used for "High School" or "Corporate". This question is unanswerable.

Comment: My best answer... "blue" .. that's about as useful as any answer you'll receive.

Comment: @Scott Man it's getting a little tense in here. I didn't want to start any trouble over colors.

I've seen many other opinionated questions on this site and they all get some useful feed back. I was just hoping for the same. Guess it's not a good day to talk about colors.

I appreciate the feedback though.
Blue, yeah that's a good choice! I think corporate would definitely fall under that category.

Comment: Not tense at all :) At least not on this end :) Some subjective questions are allowed, if they are answerable based upon experience and some reference. But completely open-ended "what do you like" questions are just too opinion-based to be helpful. Just because I like green, it doesn't mean it can be supported that green is appropriate or inappropriate for almost any use. You could reword the question to be less opinion based. Something like "When choosing a 6 color theme, is it best to use analoguous, triads, complementary... colors"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm.. I think your question is very difficult, because answers could be wildly random: any colour could do pretty much any job, it is utterly dependent on context. You could have a pink university, and you could have a shocking yellow business. Context is everything. Then of course; how you use that pink or screaming yellow: it could work, if supporting colours and design elements are good talent cast in supporting roles.

All that said, as a brainstorming on the extremely generic categories, here is a very quickly thrown-toghether thing. It would need hours of refinement, but in the case of a colour for a category, my brainstorming would start here.

- Light green for high school (youth)
- Bold red for uni (we are bold, and know what we are doing!)
- Blue-green for millitary (insignia, branches)
- Pale blue for corporate (mild, gentle, traditional, steady)
- Dullish grey-blue-ish for business (solid no-nonsense)
- Warm yellow for charities (hope)

However, if you ask for colours that would *indicate* the categories, as in a list, I would make them all a little more uniform.

Just a thought.

[image]

Comment: Wish I knew why this got downvoted...

Comment: thank you for the input. I like your choices as well as the reasons your picked those colors. I don't know why people keep down voting. Probably because my question is opinion based and I guess that's frowned upon here. But you have been very helpful. I appreciate you input and the effort you put into the color chart.

Comment: No worries; besides it was entirely from the top of my head. It was pretty spontaneous, should I develop one of them further, it would of course be hours of tweaking. Not sure if I see how this is more opinion-based than some of the other questions.